# CSS opening and closing ul menu with transition not workng as it should

Tags: html, css, transition

I'm trying to make a simple 2 stage ul menu on a page and am applying a transition to the second level ul, for smother opening and closing, and i cant get it working.
It opens slowly, but doesnt close slowly.

[Here](http://codepen.io/MCslo/pen/cenAb) is the example code.

If you could just give it a quick glance i would be very grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you are only animating the max-height but you are also setting the height to 0. This means that it goes to 0 before it has chance to animate. I changed the height to auto in the initial UL state

[ANSWER DEMO](http://codepen.io/2ne/pen/AqhfE)

Comment: Thanks you for taking the time and giving me a solution, works like a charm.